# Return to 301 doesn't work on nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

This is a well discussed issue of www.domain.com vs domain.com on nginx. For some reason it doesn't work. Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server{

server_name www.xyz.com;
return 301 $scheme://xyz.com$request_uri;
}


server {

    server_name xyz.com;
    access_log /home/access_logs/shiv/access.log;
    error_log  /home/access_logs/shiv/error.log;
    root /home/xyz;




    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        index index.html;

        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/xyz$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Please point out as to whats wrong with this config !!

**QUESTION**

xyz.com opens just fine.

www.xyz.com just doesn't open

**MY DNS ZONE FILE**

```
$TTL    1800
@       IN  SOA ns1.abc.com.    hostmaster.xyz. (
            1376913474 ; last update: 2013-08-19 11:57:54 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
        IN  NS  ns1.cpp.com.
            NS  ns2.cpp.com.
            NS  ns3.cpp.com.
            MX 0    9d209d3837fd2a499a12e566975cce.pamx1.hotmail.com.
@   IN A    192.xxx.xxx.154
www IN A    192.xxx.xxx.154
```

Comment: do you mind adding a comment before downvoting? Just downvoting without a reason doesn't actually help !

Comment: do you enter those manually, or is there a dns manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you didn't define that `www` subdomain, go to your dns manager and make sure that `www` points to the same ip or name server

Comment: I think you need to remove the `.` from `www.`

Comment: fixed the . but still the same!

Comment: can you ping the `www` url ?

Comment: alright that works. Was just the problem of DNS propagation delay !!